# Summation of n terms of series using calculus

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've been struggling through a problem which says, 
*Find the sum of n terms of the following series using calculus..*

$$S(x)= \sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{2^r}{x²^r+1}$$

I tried by substituting $x$ to $\frac{1}{x}$ (for $x\ne0$ and $x\ne1$ for obvious reasons) so that I can form something like this..

$$\sum_{r=0}^{r=n} x\frac{2^r  x²^r}{(x²^r+1)x}$$

Now, let $x²^r+1$ be $t$ so that,

$$\frac{dt}{dx} = x\frac{2^r  x²^r}{(x²^r+1)x}$$

Formed a differential equation,

$$\frac{S(x) dx}{x}= \sum_{r=x+1}^{r=x²^n +1} \frac{dt}{t}$$

But method doesn't seem to yield the  correct answer. Let me know if I'm wrong anywhere with appropriate correction, or alternative method. Thanks!

Comment: A few issues that are (probably) *not* your problem, but make following your post harder: (1) don't change the definition of $x$ - so substitute $x = 1/u$, not $x$ for $1/x$. (2) your formula for $\frac {dt}{dx}$ has an extra $x$ factor in it (but it is evidently a typo because it doesn't occur in your final formula). (3) the thing you did with $r$ in the final formula is just plain wrong. And replacing $r$ with $t$ in the summation limits would still be wrong. Just accept that $t \equiv t_r$ depends on $r$ and $r$ still sums from $0$ to $n$.

Comment: I said "probably" above because it could be the redefinition of $x$ that is giving you the wrong answer. If you have find a formula for $S$ by your method, you might want to see if replacing $x$ by $1/x$ in it gives you the correct answer.

Comment: Which one is correct? $S(x)= \sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{2^r}{x^{2r}+1}$ or

$S(x)= \sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{2^r}{x{^{2^r}}+1}$

Answer (score 0):

$S_n(x)= \sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{2^r}{x^{2r}+1}$ can be completed to Riemann sum:

$S_n(x)= {1\over n}\sum_{r=0}^{n}n\frac{(2^{r/n})^n}{[(x^2)^{r/n}]^n+1}$

We have the following integral:

$S_n(x)=$$\int_0^1\frac{n2^{un}}{{(x^2)}^{un}+1}du$

Introducing $t=2^{un}$ and $du=$$\frac{dt}{nt{ln2}}$ we receive that

$S_n(x)=$${1\over{ln2}}\int_1^{2^n}\frac{dt}{{(x^2)}^{lnt\over{ln2}}+1}$

Introducing $y={(x^2)}^{lnt\over{ln2}}$ (x not equals to zero)

and $dt=$$\frac{dy}{2{y}{ln|x|}\over{ln2}}$ we receive that

$S_n(x)=$${1\over{2ln|x|}}\int_1^{2n}{dt\over{y(1+y)}}$=${1\over{2ln|x|}}\int_1^{2n}\big({1\over y}-{1\over(1+y)}\big)dy$

Finally
$S_n(x)={1\over{2ln|x|}}$$\big(ln{2\over(1/n+2)}+ln2\big)$ and if $n =\infty$

then $S(x)=$$ln2\over{2ln|x|}$.

If $x=0$ then $S_n(0)=$$\sum_{r=0}^{n}{2^r}$.